# Properties of a specific subgroup of $GL_2(k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, algebraic-groups

**Question:**

Let $k$ be a field. Consider the subgroup $B\subset GL_2(k)$ where

$$B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}: a,b,d\in k, ad\neq 0\right\}$$

a) Let $Z$ be the center of $GL_2(k)$. Show that
$$\bigcap_{x\in GL_2(k)}x^{-1}Bx=Z.$$

b) Assume $k$ is algebraically closed. Show that
$$\bigcup_{x\in GL_2(k)}x^{-1}Bx=GL_2(k)$$

**Answer**

For the part (a), I know that $Z=\{\lambda I_2:\lambda\in k^* \}$. This trivially yields one inclusion as $Z\subset B$. Also, I managed to show that any element from $\bigcap x^{-1}Bx$ must be diagonal. However, I couldn't show why it must be a scalar matrix.

For the part (b), again one inclusion is obvious. However, I couldn't show the reverse one. Actually, I found a counter example for the case where $k$ is not algebraically closed but I do not see clearly why we need $k$ to be algebraically closed.

Any help/hint would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), an element $g$ in the intersection must be upper triangular with respect to every choice of basis. Therefore $g$ preserves (set wise) each line through the origin in $k^2$. This implies, first, your observation that $g$ must be diagonal, and second, that $g$ must be scalar since if the diagonal entries are distinct then $g$ does not preserve the line spanned by the vector $e_1+e_2$ (where $e_1$ and $e_2$ are the standard basis vectors).

For (b), if $k$ is algebraically closed, then any element $g \in \mathrm{GL}_2(k)$ has an eigenvector $v \in k^2$. Choose $w$ so that $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent; then the matrix of $g$ with respect to the basis $(v,w)$ is upper triangular. Hence $g \in x B x^{-1}$ where $x$ is the matrix with columns $v$ and $w$.

Comment: I didn't understand few things. Why would any element from the intersection have to be upper triangular? If we take $$x=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},$$ we would obtain a lower triangular matrix. (actually I use this matrix to show diagonality) Also, why would being upper triangular imply preserving each line through origin?

Comment: @confused The elements of $B$ are upper triangular; the elements of $x B x^{-1}$ are of course not, in general. But they *are* upper triangular in terms of the basis whose elements are the columns of $x$. So if $g$ belongs to *every* such subgroup, then $g$ must be upper-triangular with respect to *every* choice of basis of $V$. Now suppose you have a line in $V$. This line is spanned by some non-zero vector $v_1$, and you can choose $v_2$ so that $v_1,v_2$ is a basis of $V$. To say $g$ is upper triangular wrt this basis implies in particular that it stabilizes the line spanned by $v_1$.

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks a lot...